# a solution for counting sequential events in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example data, and I'd like to count action(page_number=2) and action(page_number=3) one time for each try if it is available. I have attached the result I mean. I want to do using pandas dataframe but I don't know how it is.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'action': ['enter', 'next', 'prev', 'error', 'exit'], 
                   'page_number': [0, 1, 2, 3]})
```

For example, we have this data

```
action     page_number
enter      
next        1
prev        2
next        1
next        2
exit        3
enter       
next        1
error       
next        1
error
error
error
next        2
prev        3
prev        2
next        1
prev        2
prev        1
exit        0
enter 
exit
```

The result I want to achieve is (**for session 1**):

```
action                   
enter                     1
next(page number = 1)     1
next(page number = 2)     1
prev(page number = 2)     1
exit                      1
```

**next(page number = 1)**  appears **twice** in the first session but I want to count it just **once**. Even if it occurs 3 times in the first session but I want to count it just once. I'd like to have this rule in all the sessions for all the actions. Each action counts just once in each session.

Thank you in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we create a new column 'extended_action' and then groupby this new column:

```
df['extended_action'] = (df.action + ' (page number = ' + df.page_number.astype(str) + ')').where(df.action.isin(('next', 'prev')), df.action)
df.groupby('extended_action').extended_action.count()
```

Result (for the whole example dataframe):

```
extended_action
enter                     3
error                     4
exit                      3
next (page number = 1)    5
next (page number = 2)    2
prev (page number = 1)    1
prev (page number = 2)    3
prev (page number = 3)    1
```

---

You can rename the columns after the groupby to get the output in the requested format:

```
df.groupby('extended_action',as_index=False).action.count().rename(columns={'extended_action': 'action', 'action': 'count'})
```

Result:

```
                   action  count
0                   enter      3
1                   error      4
2                    exit      3
3  next (page number = 1)      5
4  next (page number = 2)      2
5  prev (page number = 1)      1
6  prev (page number = 2)      3
7  prev (page number = 3)      1
```

---

**UPDATE as per comment below:**

If you need the count per session (a session lasts from `enter` to `exit`) then you need to insert a session number column and group by `session` and `extended_action`:

```
df['session'] = df.action.eq('enter').cumsum()
df.groupby(['session','extended_action']).extended_action.count()
```

Result:

```
session  extended_action       
1        enter                     1
         exit                      1
         next (page number = 1)    2
         next (page number = 2)    1
         prev (page number = 2)    1
2        enter                     1
         error                     4
         exit                      1
         next (page number = 1)    3
         next (page number = 2)    1
         prev (page number = 1)    1
         prev (page number = 2)    2
         prev (page number = 3)    1
3        enter                     1
         exit                      1
```

**UPDATE 2 as per changed question and comment below:**
If you want to count each event only once you just need to `drop_duplicates` before the grouping:

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['session','extended_action']).extended_action.count()
```

Result:

```
session  extended_action       
1        enter                     1
         exit                      1
         next (page number = 1)    1
         next (page number = 2)    1
         prev (page number = 2)    1
2        enter                     1
         error                     1
         exit                      1
         next (page number = 1)    1
         next (page number = 2)    1
         prev (page number = 1)    1
         prev (page number = 2)    1
         prev (page number = 3)    1
3        enter                     1
         exit                      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for action = next (page number = 1), the number in the example result is 2 not 5. In other words, I want to count them just once for each session(between enter and exit actions)

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention this in your question and your sample data don't match your code the generate them nor does the desired result match the sample data. I updated my answer for counting per session based on the example data shown in your question.

Comment: The idea for adding the session column is excellent. Thank you. But I have edited the results in the question and write some explanations. Please read it. By the way, Thanks

Comment: Also, I can't see the column that is the number of extended_actions when I run the codes above. @Stef

Comment: I updated my answer as requested. I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "I can't see the column that is the number of extended_actions"

Comment: My problem solved which I mentioned in the last comment. Thank you for all of your answers.